# ¿Cómo hacer funcionar una función?

Tags: php, javascript

Lo que pasa es que tengo en un HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="e" placeholder="Nickname"/>
<input type="button" onclick="window.tbo(document.getElementById('e').value);" value="Comprobar">
```

Y luego en un archivo llamado gallery.php

```
<script>

    window.tbo = function(n) {

        var t = document.getElementById("circular2");
        var r = /gyev/gi;

        if(r.test(n)) {

            t.style.border = "4px solid #bf8f00";

        }

    };

</script>
```

Pero el HTML me da el error que `window.tbo` ***no*** es una función, que tiene que ver que el archivo sea `PHP`?, ***porque no puedo cambiarle*** el formato del PHP a ningún otro

Anexo los archivos:

HTML: view-source:http://beta.ogar.pw/

PHP: view-source:http://beta.ogar.pw/include/gallery.php

Comment: y no puedes cargar el código en un archivo `.js`?

Answer (score 0):

En realidad estas tratando de llamar la funcion `tbo()` de la clase `window`, pero la clase `window` no tiene ninguna funcion llamada `tbo()`.

La declaracion correcta seria:

```
function tbo(n){
      /*Lo que quieres que haga la funcion.*/
}
```

Y para llamarla en el click y pasar el parametro:

```
<input type="button" onclick="tbo(document.getElementById('e').value);" value="Comprobar">
```

No te preocupes, no influye en la escritura de HTML el que el archivo tenga extension .php, a lo mucho puedes llegar a tener problemas solamente con tu editor por no interpretar bien las etiquetas pero no con los navegadores.

Comment: Mm no me funciono

Comment: ¿Puedes ser más especifico con que no funciono?

En el fiddle que hice aquí funciona perfectamente.

https://jsfiddle.net/3oc6pav7/2/

Answer (score 0):

El código se ve correcto.

Asegurate que estas incluyendo la referencia en el html

```
<script src="/include/gallery.php"></script>
```

No tiene nada que ver que el archivo tenga extension php, pero eso sí, asegurate que la cabecera `Content-Type` de la respuesta `HTTP` sea `text/javascript`

Puedese hacerlo con la funcion `header` de PHP:

```
<?php
  header("Content-Type: text/javascript");
```

Comment: Mm no me funciono

Comment: ¿ @EduardoSebastian Puedes explicar mejor por qué no funcionó ? Quiero decir, ¿ qué error aparece, el mismo ?. Ademas creo que seria util en tu pregunta que pongas todo el codigo.